# Network sharing on Windows 7 / Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-10.10

How do i go about sharing an internet connection on my Windows 7 machine with an Ubuntu machine?
Please note the Ubuntu machine does not have internet connection so i cannot install programs on it.
All i want to do is share the internet connection on my windows 7 pc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 7 and you want to do ICS(Internet Connection Sharing) to any Windows,Linux,Mac or Other os. It's not possible as per my knowledge.

If you want to use the ICS(Internet Connection Sharing) simply do one thing Install Windows XP and you can easily use internet on both Desktop.